# flutter reordable_grid_view package child white background

Tags: flutter, gridview, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-gridview

I am using flutter recordable grid view package [recordable_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/reorderable_grid_view)

And it puts a white background behind my custom widgets while dragging.

How to make it transparent or how to give it rounded borders.
It makes the layout looks so ugly.
[image: Image example]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikoloz Miruashvili's answer returns an error if using some Material widgets like `Chip`. This is working for me in that case:

```
dragWidgetBuilder: (index, widget) =>
                          Material(
                             color: Colors.transparent,
                             child: widget
                             ),
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very late but I just had this issue and managed to resolve it, so if anyone needs it here it goes:
You can use the dragWidgetBuilder which allows you to apply any custom effects to the widget being dragged. If you don't want any effects to be applied (Including the white background and the ugly shadow), you can simply add this to ReorderableGridView constructor:

```
dragWidgetBuilder: (index, widget) => widget
```